# How to configure my _htaccess for deployment

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble when I deploy an app that I was given, my links dont work and I get a not found error, however when I run it localy everything works.
I am pretty sure that the problem lies within my htaccess file and the fact that to run it localy the developer who made the app added a server.php file in the root directory that says it allows the app to run localy. So I think I have to modify the htaccess or do something to mimic what the server.phpfile does localy when I deploy.
Also when I deploy I make the root go to \public for me to get the homepage.

This is my server.php:

```
<?php

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

And this is my default htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I have played with it quite a bit to try and get it to work with no luck, I have changed for example where it says REQUEST_FILENAME to REQUEST_URI, I have removed the whole IfModule section, etc.., but I ussuallly code in js and use node so I dont really know much of the syntax or what is going on here.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with your .htaccess file. Try giving permission(777) to bootstrap and storage folder and then check. Also if you can show us screenshot of your error then it would be helpful.

Comment: If your site is at `public/`, you need to adjust your webserver configuration; namely, changing the document root to the `public/` folder. This will likely make `.htaccess` work correctly.

Comment: I did change the root to load from public which allows me to see the index page but the links dont work.

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi I didnt SS the errors because its different depending on where I deploy, on heroku and AWS I got a plain 404 server not found page, and on azure I get The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: @Jack Next thing to check will be webserver config. Check that a) you're using Apache at all and b) that `.htaccess` overrides are permitted by your Apache config.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks I did check that, doesnt seem to be the issue Heroku Docs say method override is set to all as default and even though I didnt find what is said on the others im pretty sure they are also set to enable since when I make changes  to my htaccess I do sometimes see different results, none good though,